# How to count the number of google searches done to reach to an answer in java?

Tags: java, google-search

So I am making this app wherein a user has to find answer of a particular question using google search, winner being the one who finds the answer in minimum number of searches.
I tried making this app in java, by opening a separate browser google.com window. But there are many faults in this app, as in what happens when the user opens the link in a new tab/windows or opens a new google.com page, or uses any other search engine to find the answer. All those searches do not get counted in my app.
So how do I proceed making this app?

Comment: Maybe a Chrome/Firefox (or other) web browser plugin?